# The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this in a web applicaiton

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I am working on a web project. The server of the project uses SignalR. I am getting this error "The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this" only in release version and at time when user attempts to login. When login button is pressed again this error doesn't come up. I'm not sure what could be reason and how to resolve it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: No, but on server side I am using a utility dll originally made for desktop application (which has stuff for displaying message boxes, but that part is not getting used in web app).

Comment: It sounds like crap code in that dll then.

Comment: Yup I know, any suggestion how could this issue be resolved. I am not having this issue in debug version and also why does it let user to login 2nd time.

Comment: Rewrite the code or modify the utility DLL's code.

Comment: How long does it take to comment out a line of code throwing that exception?

Comment: leppie I appreciate your response but unfortunately that's not possible as this dll is part of a middle layer that  communicates with server and has lot of stuff specific to the way how it communicates with server. Our desktop app is already using this dll to communicate with server. So due to the complexity and time constraint we just used this dll in the middle layer of our web app that communicates with server.